# Pytest object created by object assert_called_once_with

Tags: python-3.x, object, pytest

I known how I can test if an injected object was called with a specific argument.  But in my case the injected object will create an object that object will create another object and I want to test if that last object was called with the right argument.

in the example below the question would be if c.dirve was called with 100 as argument:

```
class car:
    def drive(self, distance):
        print("so fast")


class car_shop:
    def buy_car(self):
        return car()


class shop_shop:
    def buy_shop(self):
        return car_shop()


class processor:
    def __init__(self, sshop):
        self.sshop = sshop


    def run(self):
        cshop = self.sshop.buy_shop()
        c = cshop.buy_car()
        c.drive(100)


def main():
    sshop = shop_shop()
    proc = processor(sshop)
    proc.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

is there a way to test that?

Since this was requested here my approach for testing these objects:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock

from object_returns_object_test_for_arguments import processor, shop_shop

@pytest.fixture
def mock_shop_shop():
    return Mock(spec=shop_shop)

def test_processor_car_called_with_100(mock_shop_shop):
   proc = processor(mock_shop_shop)
   proc.run()
   assert mock_shop_shop.car_shop.car.drive.assert_called_once_with(100)
   assert mock_shop_shop.car_shop.car.drive.call_count == 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using just the code shown in the question, you only have to mock `car.drive`. This could be done for example this way:

```
from unittest import mock

from object_returns_object_test_for_arguments import processor, shop_shop


@mock.patch('object_returns_object_test_for_arguments.car.drive')
def test_processor_car_called_with_100(drive_mock):
    proc = processor(shop_shop())
    proc.run()
    drive_mock.assert_called_once_with(100)
```

As I don't know your real code, you may have to mock more stuff.
As an aside: class names in Python are written upper-case, camelcase-style by default.

Comment: thank you, it works so far the only thing is that pytest does not know call:  "NameError: name 'call' is not defined"
do I need to import it from somewhere. python version: 3.4.9
pytest version 4.6.3

Comment: Actually, you can use `assert_called_once_with` - don't remember why I didn't use that.

Comment: assert_called_onec_with can be dangerous since a mock object returns true for any method by default. meaning any typo will break the test. maybe that is the reason. also why i used call_count == 1 up top.

Comment: I don't think that this is a problem - this would always fail if you have a typo there. No mock object is automatically _called_, it is just that _if_ it is called it returns another mock object, but the return value is not checked by `assert_called_once_with`.